# Unable to install Navigation in android

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to install the latest release Navigation in Architecture components .
i am following this document [Tutorial link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components)

When i am trying to sync it is giving error .

```
Could not find androidx.navigation:safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/safe-args-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha01/safe-args-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha01.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/navigation/safe-args-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha01/safe-args-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha01.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/navigation/safe-args-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha01/safe-args-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha01.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/navigation/safe-args-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha01/safe-args-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha01.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

**Module Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ard.navigationapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version' // use -ktx for Kotlin
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version' // use -ktx for Kotlin

    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version' // use -ktx for Kotlin

}

apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
```

**Project Gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        classpath "androidx.navigation:safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alph

a01"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That artifact does not seem to exist, based on what's in https://maven.google.com right now. Try `android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01` instead. See also [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79454383).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
classpath "android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

instead of

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

If you're not concerned with type-safety of argument, you can skip the **Safe args** part and you will be good to go with Navigation Component.